# Can I display Tag name of Git in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, github, git-tag

I use Github in my project with Android Studio 3.4.1. I add a Tag name *Milestone_A* for a commit, please see Image A.

1： How can I set in order to see the Tag name *Milestone_A* in Log view ? At present there only a icon is displayed, I have to hover mouse and see the tag name from Hint.

2： Will the tag name *Milestone_A* be synchronized to remote Github, or is it only stored local disk ?

**Image A**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adressing the second part, about tag syncing**

No, the sending part needs to be explicitly done.

To send tags, you can either check the "Push tags" box in the push dialog of Android Studio before you push a branch, or alternatively, at any time even without the need to push a branch, open the console and fire a simple `git push --tags`

For the other part, receiving tags, new ones will be fetched from the remote end each time you `fetch` or `pull` (from both CLI or GUI).

Comment: Thanks! your ways  for  the second part is great!

Comment: @HelloCW Unfortunately, I'm unable to help you on the first part, I hope a peer will promptly add an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Addressing the first part (Android Studio 4.2.2)**

I've also researched for the tag names in the panel, and I was able to find where it is. It was open by default on Linux but it's closed by default on Windows, apparently.

Here is how to do it:

1. In the git log, find the eye icon called **Presentation Settings**:

[image: git panel]

[image: git panel 2]

2. Check the **Show tag names** option after clicking to **Presentation Settings**.

[image: git panel 3]

There are also other formatting options that could be useful to some people.